# Finding negative powers of polynomial expressions

Tags: polynomials, code-request

Suppose I have the following expressions

```
f = am9*x^{-9} + am8*x^{-8} + am7*x^{-7} + am6 x^{-6} + am5 x^{-5} + am4 x^{-4} + am3 x^{-3} + am2 x^{-2} + am1 x^{-1}+ a0 + a1 x^{1} + a2 x^{2};
```

I want to make some function that reads the negative powers and zeroth power only.

```
  function[f]=am9*x^{-9} + am8*x^{-8} + am7*x^{-7} + am6 x^{-6} + am5 x^{-5} + am4 x^{-4} + am3 x^{-3} + am2 x^{-2} + am1 x^{-1}+ a0
```

Comment: Why are these powers inside lists?

Comment: @Syed:  it may be a syntax error that the OP doesn't realize they've made;  the quantity evaluates and returns a list with the desired polynomial as its only element.

Comment: @Syed, I was confused with the tex, thanks for alerting me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
f = am9*x^(-9) + am8*x^(-8) + am7*x^(-7) + am6 x^(-6) + am5 x^(-5) + 
  am4 x^(-4) + am3 x^(-3) + am2 x^(-2) + am1 x^(-1) + a0 + a1 x^(1) + 
  a2 x^(2)


Select[f, (Exponent[#, x] <= 0 &)]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Normal[Series[f, {x, 0, -1}]]

(* {am9/x^9 + am8/x^8 + am7/x^7 + am6/x^6 + am5/x^5 + am4/x^4 + am3/x^3 + am2/x^2 + am1/x} *)
```

The `Series` function expands the expression in a power series in `x` about `x = 0` and keeps all terms up to order `-1`.  The output of `Series` is a `SeriesData` object; `Normal` turns this into a "normal" polynomial.

---

(Also, as noted in the comments, in Mathematica the curly brackets `{}` are reserved for lists.  Use parentheses `()` to specify the order of operations.)